# Monkey Theorem - pick random letters until input string is generated

Tags: python

I wanted to make a code resembles the infinite monkey theorem
**the theorem states that:**

> a monkey hitting keys at random on a typewriter keyboard for infinite
>   amount of time will almost surely type a given text such as the
>   complete works of Shakespeare.

well , suppose we replace a monkey with a python to generate one sentence of Shakespeare ? and calculate the trials

for example: "methinks it is like a weasel"

Here is what I wrote:

```
def Monkey_Theorem(sentence):
    sentence.lower()
    string_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    import random
    a = []
    l = ''
    x = 0
    trials = 0
    while x < (len(sentence) - 1):
        trials += 1
        z = random.choice(string_letters)
        if z == sentence[x]:
            a.append(z)
            x += 1
        elif z == " ":
            trials -= 1
            a.append(" ")
        if x > (len(sentence) - 1):
            l = ''.join(l)
            break
    return l and trials
```

I wrote this into python 2.7 IDLE , pressed enter then wrote:

```
Monkey_Theorem("methinks it is like a weasel")
```

after that I pressed enter.. it moved to the next line and didn't come up with the (>>>)

and after sometime no result and when trying to close the IDLE with despair on my face , it says program still running

**HERE'S THE QUESTION :**

(A) is the while loop an infinite one ??
(B) or my IDLE is slow ??
(C) other cause
and how to fix the reason

**One more request** 
how to detect the case if I encounter this situation in the future whether it's (A) , (B) , (C)?

Comment: http://www.annedawson.net/Python_Editor_IDLE.htm

Comment: What are you expecting `l and trials` to even return? Hint: It won't be two values

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment.

Comment: I tried both answers are good..  And the site don't accept upvotes whos reputation less than 15 I honstly upvote the answers.. And every answer cover a problem so I cannot choose only one

Comment: Note that your sentence (*methings it ...*) contains spaces, but you're passing only letters to `random.choice()`. Also note that there are 27 ** 28 = 11972515182562019788602740026717047105681 possible strings of length 28 containing only letters and spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print something within the loop to see if it is infinite... For example, if `z` is never equal to the `sentence[x]`, then you won't increment it, and the loop never stops.

That will happen when you need to guess a space character because you have not put one into your string. Therefore, even `elif z == " ":` will never be entered.

Here is a working version of your code.

Some things to note: Keeping track of `a` or `l` is pointless. At the end of the function, you will be returning the exact same input as `sentence`. Also, there is a simple import to get all the english letters.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alpha
import random

# add space character to possible choices
alpha += ' '

def Monkey_Theorem(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    x = 0
    trials = 0
    while x < len(sentence):
        trials += 1
        z = random.choice(alpha)
        if z == sentence[x]:
            if z == " ": # this isn't really necessary
                trials -= 1
            print "guessed %s at trial %d" % (z, trials)
            x += 1
    return trials

trials = Monkey_Theorem("hello world")
print "number of trials = ", trials
```

Output

```
guessed h at trial 49
guessed e at trial 52
guessed l at trial 58
guessed l at trial 107
guessed o at trial 145
guessed   at trial 157
guessed w at trial 168
guessed o at trial 197
guessed r at trial 232
guessed l at trial 248
guessed d at trial 269
number of trials =  269
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the code..  I appreciate alot your help

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you set `string_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`. Notice that there is no space in `string_letters`, so when you have matched the entire first word `'methinks'` it is impossible to match the space after that word. So your loop continues infinitely.

You can solve that particular problem by adding a space to the end of the definition string of `string_letters`. But as others are pointing out, your code has other problems as well.

As for detecting which it is, include a way to stop your loop by a keypress or pressing ctrl+C or something similar. Then print the value of `trials` and see if it is a *very* large number. If so, you have an infinite or extremely long-running loop.

Comment: Thanks alot for advice and ctrl c tip.. I appreciate this alot